# Apollo Client how to send locally cached mutations to the server

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

I'm trying to send all my locally cached mutations to the server on user request.
The idea is that there's a "Save Changes" button in the UI which allows the user to update the remote db with all the locally aplied changes.

Example: I have a users object in the cache:

```
"User:1": {
   name: "Tom",
   enabled: true
},
"User:2": {
   name: "John",
   enabled: true
}
```

Now, let's say the UI user disables both users by setting `enabled: false` and presses "Save changes". At this point, I'd like all the local changes to be send; both objects should be send to *remote* and persisted there.
I tried several approaches but they all lead to rather hacky code.
Is there any *canonic* way of doing it?

Not sure if that's relevant, but I'm using "Hot Chocolate" graphql server for C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There is nothing like "locally cached mutations".**

**By writing to the cache you just mutate results of other operations** (queries or mutations). There is nothing like "local queue", "local copy to be updated on sync" etc. - it is just a cache. You can write to it to save/avoid unnecessary queries after mutations (especially for related types).

To create "Save Changes" feature just read data from cache and use it in mutation - probably special one, accepting arrays as arguments/input types. If no such mutation available/permited you can try to connect many (aliased) mutations into one request.

Comment: fair enough about the wording. regarding the solution - this is pretty much what I've figured out so far. I was hoping there's a better way of doing it. The problem seems fairly standard and I'm quite surprised I haven't been able to find a package that would address it.

Comment: Not needed? What for? Local changes shouldn't be stored in cache - it is a part of preparing mutation - just keep it in local, component state (or Formik) and use at once in one, single, classic mutation.

Comment: I am using Apollo for local state management. This part works well, except that to my surprise there's no way of communicating that state back to the remote. I think I will do it the way you say. I will create a special mutation on the server-side and push all the changes through that.